# remove elements from array in ruby

Tags: ruby

I have an array and I want to remove some elements. I tried this but it doesn't work:

```
@restaurants.each_with_index do |restaurant, i|

if (restaurant.stars > 3)  @restaurants.slice!(i)     end

end
```

How can I do it?

Comment: You will find the answer below from Hck. But you could have found that easily by looking at the documentation first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `Array#delete_at(index)`: see [rubydoc](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-i-delete_at)

But the best way for you will be to use `reject!` ([rubydoc](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-i-reject-21)) or `delete_if` ([rubydoc](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-i-delete_if)).

Answer (score 4):

```
@restaurants.reject!{|restaurant| restaurant.stars > 3}
```

Answer (score 0):

If restaurants is an array you can use pop, e.g.

```
a = [ "a", "b", "c", "d" ]
a.pop     #=> "d"
a.pop(2)  #=> ["b", "c"]
a         #=> ["a"]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@restaurants.reject! {|restaurant| restaurant.stars > 3}
```